# Intense loop freezing browser; how to make server do it?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, client-server

Basic outline; I am retrieving ~100 Facebook statuses, and running a search of these posts to check if it contains one of ~20 search terms. When I try to run it in the browser it locks up, which makes me apprehensive to try and run this on the client side.

What would be the easiest way to have the server run this operation and return the results? Can I do it in Python? Here is the loop, for reference.

```
    function Filter() {
    console.log("running Filter")
    //loop through fbObj.posts
    for (i = 0, l = fbObj.length; i < l; i++){
        var post = fbObj[i].post
        console.log("Checking " + post + " for search terms")
        //loop through searchTerms
        for (j = 0; j<searchTermObj.length; j= j++) {
            searchTerm_variants = searchTermObj[j].words
            for (x = 0; x <  searchTerm_variants.length; x++){
                if (post.indexOf(searchTerm_variants[x]) !== 0){
                    foundPosts[i] = {}
                    foundPosts[i] = fbObj[i]
                }
            }   
        }
    console.log(foundPosts) 
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do this on the server. You just need a better way to do it.  You can probably combine all the search terms into a single (monstrous, admittedly) regular expression, and then let the runtime's regex engine do its best. It will almost certainly be more efficient than what you've got.

Comment: Any advice/links as to how to make this happen?

Comment: Well I'm guessing that you've got what amounts to a list of simple words.  You can build a regex by just concatenating them with "|".  I'll see if I can type in a sketch of how to do that in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code that might explain the lockup :

```
//loop through searchTerms
for (j = 0; j<searchTermObj.length; j= j++) {
```

j is never incremented (so it is always 0) :

j++ increments j, but evaluates to j which is assigned to j. So it's a null operation.

Therefore your code gets stuck in the loop.

Comment: I think that was a typo and it locked up regardless but I will doublecheck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using worker threads to do this on the client?  However this might be available only in the latest builds of various browsers?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Worker

Answer (score 1):

You could build an all-encompassing regex like this, I think:

```
var regexWords = [], variants;
for (var i = 0; i < searchTermObj.length; ++i) {
  variants = searchTermObj[i].words;
  for (var j = 0; j < variants.length; ++j)
    regexWords.push(variants[j]);
}

var regex = new RegExp(regexWords.join("|"));
```

Then you can test each post like this:

```
for (i = 0, l = fbObj.length; i < l; i++){
    var post = fbObj[i].post
    if (regex.test(post)) {
      // found a naughty word in the post
    }
}
```

Now this works so long as your word lists are just alphabetic words, with no funny characters like "*" or "." in them.  You could still make this work if they did contain special characters, but it'd be a little more complex.

Doing it with a big regex like that allows the regex engine to employ smart sub-linear searching techniques, so that each post only needs to be searched once.  It still may not be extremely fast.